# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'poInfoInquiry'. - C# webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I am getting Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'poInfoInquiry' when I try to invoke poInfoInquiry method in webservices(C# - WSDL). I am passing date as DateTime type.

Exception that I have caught is below:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'poInfoInquiry'. --->
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (12, 13). --->
System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value. at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds) at 
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption) at
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDateTime(String value) at
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToDateTime(String value) at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIFH2HRemittanceIn.Read9_PaymentDetail(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIFH2HRemittanceIn.Read10_PaymentInfo(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIFH2HRemittanceIn.Read11_poInfoInquiryResponse(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderIFH2HRemittanceIn.Read18_Item() at 
Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer2.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) at 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) --- End of inner exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to go here
There is a problem in your date = DateTime

http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/hilary/archive/2010/08/27/looks-can-be-deceiving-dates-date-times-and-quot-t-quot.aspx